# Compiler throws cout'ing out of loop

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I wrote a numerical simulation and, as a tweak, I wanted to add some basic progress bar.
In the main loop I wrote:

```
if(particles.t>=pr*maxtime){
   cout << "|";
   pr+=0.01;
 }
```

Where pr starts at 0.01. So, basically it was supposed to cout one hundred "|" during the computation. Instead of that it couts these "|" at the end of the simulation, all at once.

And when I modify this code to:

```
if(particles.t>=pr*maxtime){
   cout << pr << "\n";
   pr+=0.01;
 }
```

it works as it should.

I guess it have something to do with optimization, I am compiling my code using g++, with options -Wall and -lm. Code like this worked when I wrote it in C#, a while ago.

Comment: @jal: It would change the observable behaviour, and the issue he is seeing is buffering, not optimizations.

Comment: yeah, I didn't read the code properly. My bad. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the buffering of the output. Place `cout.flush();` after each printing and the issue should be solved.

Comment: @gumol if it is working then you may need to accept it as an answer

Comment: Note that flushing the stream is also **slow**. That's why it is buffered by default. :) So depending on how frequently it's done, your "tweak" might dramatically slow down your simulation

Comment: I don't think 100 flushes will significantly slow down, when the simulation executes usually in few minutes, although I might be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The writes to `cout` (and many other streams) are buffered. If you want to make them immediately visible, you need to flush the stream:

```
if(particles.t>=pr*maxtime){
    cout << "|";
    cout.flush();
    pr+=0.01;
}
```